# Return value from SQL Server Insert command using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, insert, return-value

Using C# in Visual Studio, I'm inserting a row into a table like this:

```
INSERT INTO foo (column_name)
VALUES ('bar')
```

I want to do something like this, but I don't know the correct syntax:

```
INSERT INTO foo (column_name)
VALUES ('bar')
RETURNING foo_id
```

This would return the `foo_id` column from the newly inserted row.

Furthermore, even if I find the correct syntax for this, I have another problem: I have `SqlDataReader` and `SqlDataAdapter` at my disposal. As far as I know, the former is for reading data, the second is for manipulating data. When inserting a row with a return statement, I am both manipulating and reading data, so I'm not sure what to use. Maybe there's something entirely different I should use for this?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

[SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch.

You can use [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) to execute the insert command and retrieve the new ID in one query.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
    int newID;
    var cmd = "INSERT INTO foo (column_name)VALUES (@Value);SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
    using (var insertCommand = new SqlCommand(cmd, con)) {
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", "bar");
        con.Open();
        newID = (int)insertCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Comment: what a great example Tim, helped me a lot. Thanks for posting a question like this Neko, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: made me an error characters found after end of sql statement

Answer (score 13):

try this:

```
INSERT INTO foo (column_name)
OUTPUT INSERTED.column_name,column_name,...
VALUES ('bar')
```

**OUTPUT** can return a result set (among other things), see: [OUTPUT Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).  Also, if you insert multiple values (INSERT SELECT) this method will return one row per inserted row, where other methods will only return info on the last row.

working example:

```
declare @YourTable table (YourID int identity(1,1), YourCol1 varchar(5))

INSERT INTO @YourTable (YourCol1)
OUTPUT INSERTED.YourID
VALUES ('Bar')
```

OUTPUT:

```
YourID
-----------
1

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: This does not work when there are Triggers on the table. In that case you will get the following error: `The target table of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.` Not sure what they mean with `without INTO clause` though, since my INSERT statement does have an INTO clause...

Comment: @Louis Somers, just an plain `OUTPUT` clause will return a result set.  If you add an ``INTO`` it will be inserted into a table.  Create a table variable: `DECLARE @Temp table (xyz int, abc varchar(5))` and you can have the `OUTPUT` rows go into this table, then after the `INSERT` you can just `SELECT` the `@Temp` table to return a result set.  Use something like this: `OUTPUT INSERTED.col1, INSERTED.col2 INTO @Temp` then after the `INSERT` something like:` ;SELECT * FROM @Temp`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use @@IDENTITY for this, but I think there's some special rules/restrictions around it?

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
{
    con.Open();
    string query = "INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (@value)";

    var command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    command.Parameters.Add("@value", value);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    command.Parameters.Clear();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";

    int identity = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

Comment: [You should really use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and **NOT** `@@IDENTITY` - that might return surprisingly wrong results!](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)