# Grab record ID after inserting the record

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to grab the ID of the record so that I can forward the user to another page with the information they just submitted. I looked at other questions regarding this and people suggest using SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() or OUTPUT but I'm really new to c# and SQL so I don't know exactly how to use it with my existing code. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

You can see I need to put the ID of the record I just inserted in the response.redirect.

```
pcn.Open();
pcm.Connection = pcn;

string logon_user = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].Substring(7);

var sql = String.Format(@"INSERT INTO Transfer (Status, Type, Name) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}')", '0', TypeTxtBox.Text.Replace("'", "''"), logon_user);

pcm.CommandText = sql;
pcm.ExecuteNonQuery();
pcn.Close();

Response.Redirect("View.aspx?ID=" + id);
```

Yeah, I see that there are other questions similar to this but I'm looking for exact help with my code above, don't mark this duplicate because its NOT!

Comment: you could always run `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();`

Comment: Use parameters to prevent sql-injection. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9319609/284240

Comment: This is an internal script that is only used by me and no one else, I'm not worried about SQL injection. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SCOPE_IDENTITY` gets last identity value inserted into an identity column in the scope.
`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar` executes the script and retrieves the ID.

```
        var sql = String.Format(@"INSERT INTO Transfer (Status, Type, Name) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}')  
        SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)"
    , '0', TypeTxtBox.Text.Replace("'", "''"), logon_user);

int ID = (int)pcm.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: This worked without me having to modify a ton of code thank you very very much.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly read up on parameterised SQL, don't ever use string concatenation for SQL as you are far more likely to fall foul of SQL injection!

To get the ID, you will need to update your code to look like this:

```
pcm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Transfer (Status, Type, Name) values (@status, @type, @name);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
object identifier = pcm.ExecuteScalar();
```

if your identifiers are integers, you can cast `identifier` to an int to get the value (adjust accordingly for Guids etc)

```
int id = (int)identifier;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteNonQuery. There are various ways to get the ID, but SCOPE_IDENTITY() is what I would use.

You can see an example on MSDN here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx