# Execute Insert command and return inserted Id in Sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I am inserting some values into a SQL table using C# in MVC 4. Actually, I want to insert values and return the 'ID' of last inserted record. I use the following code.

```
public class MemberBasicData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Mem_NA { get; set; }
    public string Mem_Occ { get; set; }     
}
```

ID is automatically incremented in the database when inserted.

```
public int CreateNewMember(string Mem_NA, string Mem_Occ )
{
    using (SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(Config.ConnectionString))
    {
        using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Mem_Basic(Mem_Na,Mem_Occ) VALUES(@na,@occ)",con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@na", Mem_NA);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@occ", Mem_Occ);
            con.Open();

            int modified = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) con.Close();
                return modified;
        }
    }
}
```

I know `ExecuteNonQuery` denotes the numbers affecting the row. Instead of that I use

```
int modified = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

But it's not working. Please help me for solving this. And is there any code like `cmd.ExecuteInsertAndGetID()` (not working with my code).

Comment: What do you mean with `InsertedID` ?

Comment: You can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319532/return-value-from-sql-server-insert-command-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 273, accepted):

The following solution will work with sql server 2005 and above. You can use [output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) to get the required field. inplace of id you can  write your key that you want to return. do it like this

**FOR SQL SERVER 2005 and above**

```
    using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Mem_Basic(Mem_Na,Mem_Occ) output INSERTED.ID VALUES(@na,@occ)",con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@na", Mem_NA);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@occ", Mem_Occ);
        con.Open();

        int modified =(int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) 
            con.Close();

        return modified;
    }
}
```

**FOR previous versions**

```
    using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Mem_Basic(Mem_Na,Mem_Occ)  VALUES(@na,@occ);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();",con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@na", Mem_NA);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@occ", Mem_Occ);
        con.Open();

        int modified = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) con.Close();
            return modified;
    }
}
```

Comment: int modified = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: Note that the column name must match the identity column name of the table. For example a table with this identity column name: `select EmployeeId, * from Employees` Requires this fragment in the insert statement: `output inserted.EmployeeId`

Comment: How would you check if the query actually did the insert in this case?

Comment: I was getting an invalid cast error when trying to cast the `int modified = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();` to an int.  I had to use Convert to convert it to an int. `int modified = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());`

Comment: below modification works for me.

INSERT INTO Mem_Basic(Mem_Na,Mem_Occ) output INSERTED.ID VALUES(?, ?)

Comment: Please note that "OUTPUT" wouldn't work if there is  UPDATE triggers on the table

Answer (score 62):

Change the query to

```
"INSERT INTO Mem_Basic(Mem_Na,Mem_Occ) VALUES(@na,@occ); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()"
```

This will return the last inserted ID which you can then get with `ExecuteScalar`

Comment: this shows an error "InValidCast Exception was unhandled by user code"

Comment: @neel, that is because scope_identity() returns numeric data type which you can cast only against decimal .net data type. Another way is to use Convert.To<datatype>() series of functions to avoid cast problem.

Comment: This answer is better because you don't have to type in the ID column of the table being inserted into.

Comment: SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() isn't working for me, but output INSERTED.ID is.

Comment: @TiggerToo: What version of SQL Server are you using? It is possible that Microsoft have finally deprecated `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. `OUTPUT INSERTED` appeared in IIRC SQL Server 2008 and has been the preferred way to do it since

Comment: int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); Fixed my cast error

Answer (score 23):

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[INS_MEM_BASIC]
    @na varchar(50),
    @occ varchar(50),
    @New_MEM_BASIC_ID int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Mem_Basic
    VALUES (@na, @occ)

    SELECT @New_MEM_BASIC_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

C# code:

```
public int CreateNewMember(string Mem_NA, string Mem_Occ )
{
    // values 0 --> -99 are SQL reserved.
    int new_MEM_BASIC_ID = -1971;   
    SqlConnection SQLconn = new SqlConnection(Config.ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INS_MEM_BASIC", SQLconn);

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter outPutVal = new SqlParameter("@New_MEM_BASIC_ID", SqlDbType.Int);

    outPutVal.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(outPutVal);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@na", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Mem_NA;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@occ", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Mem_Occ;

    SQLconn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SQLconn.Close();

    if (outPutVal.Value != DBNull.Value) new_MEM_BASIC_ID = Convert.ToInt32(outPutVal.Value);
        return new_MEM_BASIC_ID;
}
```

I hope these will help to you ....

You can also use this if you want ...

```
public int CreateNewMember(string Mem_NA, string Mem_Occ )
{
    using (SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(Config.ConnectionString))
    {
        int newID;
        var cmd = "INSERT INTO Mem_Basic(Mem_Na,Mem_Occ) VALUES(@na,@occ);SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";

        using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(cmd, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@na", Mem_NA);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@occ", Mem_Occ);

            con.Open();
            newID = (int)insertCommand.ExecuteScalar();

            if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) con.Close();
                return newID;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a procedure, you don't need to `select SCOPE_IDENTITY()`  you just need to `return SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and then run it with `ExecuteNonQuery` and then read the `@RETURN_VALUE` Parameter

Answer (score 1):

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N't6', N'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE t6;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N't7', N'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE t7;
GO
CREATE TABLE t6(id int IDENTITY);
CREATE TABLE t7(id int IDENTITY(100,1));
GO
CREATE TRIGGER t6ins ON t6 FOR INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT t7 DEFAULT VALUES
END;
GO
--End of trigger definition

SELECT id FROM t6;
--IDs empty.

SELECT id FROM t7;
--ID is empty.

--Do the following in Session 1
INSERT t6 DEFAULT VALUES;
SELECT @@IDENTITY;
/*Returns the value 100. This was inserted by the trigger.*/

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
/* Returns the value 1. This was inserted by the 
INSERT statement two statements before this query.*/

SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('t7');
/* Returns value inserted into t7, that is in the trigger.*/

SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('t6');
/* Returns value inserted into t6. This was the INSERT statement four statements before this query.*/

-- Do the following in Session 2.
SELECT @@IDENTITY;
/* Returns NULL because there has been no INSERT action 
up to this point in this session.*/

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
/* Returns NULL because there has been no INSERT action 
up to this point in this scope in this session.*/

SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('t7');
/* Returns the last value inserted into t7.*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS 'Identity'
```

this will return identity value inserted only within the current scope

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY AS 'Identity';
```

this is not limited to a specific scope
So this will return the latest value of the identity column and which not necessarily the identity value from the same scope.

Answer (score 1):

If you using EF:

```
 Class Person{
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

You set Name value:

```
 Person p = new Person(){
  Name = "James"
};
DbContext.Persons.Add(p);
DbContext.SaveChanges();

//p.Id = new Id from database
//p.Name = James
```

You Just Save it you will get Id from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Can use `OUTPUT Inserted.Id` in Insert query linke this:

```
INSERT INTO Mem_Basic(Mem_Na,Mem_Occ) OUTPUT INSERTED.Id VALUES(@na,@occ);
```

Store response in result variable then read result[0].Id, Or can use ExecuteSingle and read result.Id directly to access inserted id or any other col data.

Answer (score -2):

```
using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Mem_Basic(Mem_Na,Mem_Occ) " +
    "VALUES(@na,@occ);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();",con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@na", Mem_NA);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@occ", Mem_Occ);
    con.Open();

    int modified = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) con.Close();
        return modified;
}
```

**SCOPE_IDENTITY** : Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. for more details http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: Would be nice, but ExecuteNonQuery only returns the number of rows affected, not the ID. Use ExecuteScalar instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.1