# Getting output parameter from SqlCommand returns null

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have this piece of code:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
   cmd.Connection = connection;
   cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE S " +
                     "SET S.WebId = S.WebId + 1 " +
                     "OUTPUT DELETED.WebId " +
                     "FROM jcdSetting S";
   SqlParameter parameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
   parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
   int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   webId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value);
}
```

For some reason, the last line fails, the parameter I'm trying to access is always `DbNull`. I've tried the query in Management Studio and it returns the value just fine.

I've checked the return value of `ExecureNonQuery` and that as well returns 1 as expected. I'm totally lost here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373461/execute-insert-command-and-return-inserted-id-in-sql

Comment: As others have pointed out, `OUTPUT` does not define an output parameter (those are only for stored procedures); examine the result set instead. Incidentally, your `UPDATE` has no `WHERE`. This can work correctly only if `jcdSetting` has only a single row, otherwise you'll get back a table of updated values.

Comment: The table has only a single row, so no problem there :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `output` within a `update` statement, is equivalent to a select, whereas from the code you've posted you're expecting it to come out in an output parameter named @id.

Where does @id come from? you haven't defined it anywhere.

`output` in the method that you've used it would return a rowset, not a scalar value.