# Insert statement inserting 2 records instead of 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am inserting records using simple sql statement which has to enter only 1 record at a time but it is inserting 2 times ***Here is my code:***

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
       //First Query

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(code.connection);
        con.Open();
        String query = "insert into issue values(@pro_id,@impect,@type,@summary,@detail,@attach,@comment,@mem_id,@priority,@status,getdate(), @cust_name,@mail,'','','') select SCOPE_IDENTITY() ";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pro_id", "PB");
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@impect", impect);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", IssueList.SelectedItem.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@summary", summary.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@detail",detail1.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@attach", "");
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", Comments.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mem_id", "");
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@priority", "");
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "Submitted");
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust_name", "ramisha");//to be add auto
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail", "rami@gmail.com");// to be add auto
        if (com.ExecuteNonQuery() >= 1)
        {
            Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('Request issue Submitted Successfully!');</script>");
            SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader();
            if (sdr.Read())
            {
                issue_id = int.Parse(sdr[0].ToString());
                Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert(issue_id);</script>");
            }
            sdr.Close();
        }
        con.Close();

       // 2nd query

        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(code.connection);
        con2.Open();
        String query2 = "insert into contact values(@id,@cust_name,@mail,@ph_no,@time)";
        SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand(query2, con2);
        com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", issue_id);
        com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust_name", contactN);
        com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail", contactM);
        if (itsOkToCall.Checked == true)
        {
            com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ph_no", phone.Text);
            com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", FromDrop.SelectedItem.ToString() + " to " + toDrop.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ph_no", "");
            com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", "");
        }
        if (com2.ExecuteNonQuery() >= 1)
        {
            Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('Request Submitted Successfully!');window.location='Default.aspx';</script>");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('Request not Submitted Successfully!');window.location='Default.aspx';</script>");
        }

        con2.Close();
```

Here the 1st query is inserting 2 records whereas it is suppose to enter only 1 record. 2nd is inserting 1 record which is perfect. Now anyone help me where is problem

Comment: You *are* executing it twice (`com.ExecuteNonQuery()` and `com.ExecuteReader()`) ...

Comment: then what to do? I need to get value of key

Comment: @HansKesting and second one is for reading not inserting

Comment: Here is the anwser to you question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373461/execute-insert-command-and-return-inserted-id-in-sql

Comment: Do just the `com.ExecuteReader()`, or even just a [`com.ExecuteScalar()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

Comment: `com.ExecuteReader()` can read and insert as well? If i remove `com.ExecuteNonQuery`

Comment: The ExecuteNonQuery executes the INSERT and ignores results. The ExecuteReader executes the INSERT *again* and then reads the results.

Comment: @HansKesting thank you. you saved me

Comment: `ExecuteReader` suitable for `SELECT` statement, for `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` you need to use `ExecuteNonQuery` instead.