# ExecutedScalar() - ASP.NET web application

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net

I faced a problem when I try to use the `ExecutedScalar()` command.

I built a web application, in the web App the user need to fill his details like name, family, hobbies (array), etc.

After the user pushing on the submit button, I collect all the information the user fill and create an object Person and connect to DB and update the `personTbl` table.

`personTbl` - I have an `ID (identity(1,1))` filed, that means every time I add a new person he gets from SQL Server a new ID.

My question is:

How can I add a new person to DB and at the same time to get is ID from SQL Server?

I use `ExecuteNonQuery()` to insert the new person, but at the same time, I need to retrieve his ID (using `ExecutedScalar()`) because I need to use her to do another insert command to a different table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute Insert command and return inserted Id in Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373461/execute-insert-command-and-return-inserted-id-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `OUTPUT` clause.

Refer [Output Inserted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

e.g.

```
 using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table1(column1,column2,column3) output INSERTED.ID VALUES(val1,val2,val3)",con))
    {       
        con.Open();
        int id=(int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        con.Close();
        return id;
    }
```

Comment: @Gavriel: Welcome.