# How to get get data from a ExecuteSqlCommand from a Insert Into command?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do i get the value of emp_id([emp_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL) from the command below after it has been executed.

```
 db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO emptable ( emp_namefirst, emp_namemiddle) values ( {0},{1})", NewEmployeeModel.emp_namefirst, NewEmployeeModel.emp_namemiddle);
```

Comment: Alt, stop here and before continuing see what an Sql Injection is

Comment: You can't get it from that query. You must select `@@SCOPE_IDENTITY` or better yet use `OUTPUT inserted.emp_id` (which you can google). None of that will matter if someone sql injects your database though, so also google `SqlParameter`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute Insert command and return inserted Id in Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373461/execute-insert-command-and-return-inserted-id-in-sql)