# How to avoid every time initialization when value have greater than 0

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I have a method that inserts a new record after checking whether it already exists or not.

Here is my method:

```
protected void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string MobileNo = "";
    string replaceValue = txt_mobile.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "$");

    string[] values = replaceValue.Split('$');
    int uCnt = 0;
    int sCnt = 0;

    foreach (string item in values)
    {
        SaveRecord(item.Trim(),out MobileNo,out uCnt,out sCnt);
    }

    txt_mobile.Text = string.Empty;

    if(uCnt > 0)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "BulkSMS System", "alert('Mobile No(s) : "+MobileNo.TrimEnd(',')+" Already Exist');", true);
    }

    if(sCnt > 0)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "BulkSMS System", "alert('" + sCnt + " Record(s) Inserted Successfully');", true);
    }

    Get_Data();
}

public void SaveRecord(string value, out string MobileNo, out int uCnt, out int sCnt)
{
    uCnt = 0; //every time initialized to 0
    sCnt = 0; //every time initialized to 0 
    MobileNo = "";

    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        var dot = Regex.Match(value, @"\+?[0-9]{10}");

        if (dot.Success)
        {
            string str = "SELECT TOP 1 [ID],[MobileNo] FROM[dbo].[whitelistdata]";
            str += " WHERE [UserID] = '" + Convert.ToInt32(ddl_users.SelectedValue.ToString()) + "' AND [SenderId] = '" + Convert.ToInt32(ddl_senders.SelectedValue.ToString()) + "' AND [MobileNo] = '" + value + "'";
            dt = obj.Get_Data_Table_From_Str(str);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                uCnt++;
                MobileNo += value + ",";
            }
            else
            {
                string str1 = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[whitelistdata]([UserID],[SenderId],[KeywordID],[MobileNo])";
                str1 += "VALUES (" + Convert.ToInt32(ddl_users.SelectedValue.ToString()) + "," + Convert.ToInt32(ddl_senders.SelectedValue.ToString()) + ",1," + value + ")";
                obj.Execute_Query(str1);
                sCnt++;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CommonLogic.SendMailOnError(ex);
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "BulkSMS System", "alert('" + ex.Message.ToString() + "');", true);
    }
}
```

The problem is every time it's set to 0 when method has been called I want to prevent them when previous value is greater than 0.

Please help me guys..

Comment: what is previous value here? UserID, mobile? Also what is 'it'? Please edit, it will be easy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373461/execute-insert-command-and-return-inserted-id-in-sql

Comment: mobile no from database.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please first identify which combination check-in database.

if UserID AND SenderId combination Match Then

```
 string str = "SELECT TOP 1 [ID],[MobileNo] FROM[dbo].[whitelistdata]";
 str += " WHERE [UserID] = '" + Convert.ToInt32(ddl_users.SelectedValue.ToString()) + "' AND [SenderId] = '" + Convert.ToInt32(ddl_senders.SelectedValue.ToString()) + "'";
```

if check the only UserID Match Then

```
 string str = "SELECT TOP 1 [ID],[MobileNo] FROM[dbo].[whitelistdata]";
 str += " WHERE [UserID] = '" + 
     Convert.ToInt32(ddl_users.SelectedValue.ToString()) +"'";
```

if UserID OR SenderId combination Match Then

```
 string str = "SELECT TOP 1 [ID],[MobileNo] FROM[dbo].[whitelistdata]";
 str += " WHERE [UserID] = '" + Convert.ToInt32(ddl_users.SelectedValue.ToString()) + "' OR [SenderId] = '" + Convert.ToInt32(ddl_senders.SelectedValue.ToString()) + "'";
```

if UserID AND SenderId AND MobileNo combination Match Then

```
string str = "SELECT TOP 1 [ID],[MobileNo] FROM[dbo].[whitelistdata]";
str += " WHERE [UserID] = '" + Convert.ToInt32(ddl_users.SelectedValue.ToString()) + "' AND [SenderId] = '" + Convert.ToInt32(ddl_senders.SelectedValue.ToString()) + "' AND [MobileNo] = '" + value + "'";
```

Comment: Checking works fine at all i have to avoid Initialization of uCnt and sCnt when it's set to 1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ref` rather than `out` if you want to keep this design<sup>1</sup>. That means that the method can assume that the variables are already initialised and you're not forced to re-initialise them *within* the method:

```
public void SaveRecord(string value,out string MobileNo,ref int uCnt,ref int sCnt)
{
    //uCnt = 0; //initialized by caller
    //sCnt = 0; //initialized by caller
    MobileNo = ""; //?
   ....
```

And at the call site:

```
SaveRecord(item.Trim(),out MobileNo,ref uCnt,ref sCnt);
```

You'll also want to do *something* about `MobileNo` too if you expect that to *accumulate* values rather than be over-written each time through the loop. Maybe make it a [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead that you just pass normally (no `ref` or `out`) and let the `SaveRecord` method append to. `out` is definitely wrong for it.

---

<sup>1</sup>Many people would frown at a method that clearly *wants* to return values being declared `void` and making all returns via `ref`/`out`.

Something like:

```
public bool SaveRecord(string value)
{
   ...
```

Returning `true` for a new record, `false` for an existing record. I'd probably take out the exception handling from there and let the exception propagate higher before it's handled. Then the call site would be:

```
if(SaveRecord(item.Trim()))
{
   sCnt++;
}
else
{
   uCnt++;
   MobileNo += item.Trim + ","
}
```

Comment: works fine but it's not shows failed to save record if exists.

Comment: @GajjarShalin - did you pay attention to the bit where I said you'd need to sort out `MobileNo` also, but was recommending a *different* approach for it?

Comment: what was the approach for concatenating failed mobile nos and showing in message.