# Dynamic SQL Query in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, executescalar

I'm trying to create a query with a variable number of parameters, giving to the program the name of the table and an Array for the names of parameters and another array for their values.
It seems to do the work but at the instruction `ExecuteScalar()` it generates an error:

> incorrect syntax near nomeParamA...

Why?
The code :

```
 public int inserisciDato(clsParametriQuery param)
    {
        int indice = -1;
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO @tabella (";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tabella", param.nomeTabella);
            for (int i = 0; i < param.nomeParametri.Length; i++)
            {
                cmd.CommandText += "@nomeParam" + ((char)(i + 65)).ToString();
                if (i != param.nomeParametri.Length - 1)
                    cmd.CommandText += ",";
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomeParam" + ((char)(i + 65)).ToString(), param.nomeParametri[i].ToString());
            }
            cmd.CommandText += ") values (";
            for (int i = 0; i < param.valoreParametri.Length; i++)
            {
                cmd.CommandText += "'@valParam" + ((char)(i + 65)).ToString() + "'";
                if (i != param.valoreParametri.Length - 1)
                    cmd.CommandText += ",";
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valParam" + ((char)(i + 65)).ToString(), param.valoreParametri[i].ToString());
            }

            //addWithValue
            for (int i = 0; i < param.nomeParametri.Length; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomeParam" + ((char)(i + 65)).ToString(), param.nomeParametri[i].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valParam" + ((char)(i + 65)).ToString(), param.valoreParametri[i].ToString());
            }
            cmd.CommandText += ") select scope_identity()";
            indice = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
        return indice;
```

Edit:
Thanks to the comment:
-Table name and columns name must be written in the query and not as parameters
-'nameOfParamater' is not correct. You have to write just nameOfParameter
Now it works pretty good

```
public int inserisciDato(clsParametriQuery param)
    {
        //Controlla : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62192753/dinamic-query-c-sharp
        int indice = -1;
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = cn;//connessione gia istanziata
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + param.NomeTabella + " (";
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tabella", param.nomeTabella);
            for (int i = 0; i < param.NomeParametri.Length; i++)
            {
                cmd.CommandText += param.NomeParametri[i];
                if (i != param.NomeParametri.Length - 1)//changed
                    cmd.CommandText += ",";
            }
            cmd.CommandText += ") values (";
            for (int i = 0; i < param.ValoreParametri.Length; i++)
            {
                if (param.NomeTabella.ToUpper() == "CONNESSIONE")
                    cmd.CommandText += "@valParam" + ((char)(i + 65)).ToString();//changed
                else
                    cmd.CommandText += "@valParam" + ((char)(i + 65)).ToString();
                if (i != param.ValoreParametri.Length - 1)
                    cmd.CommandText += ",";
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < param.NomeParametri.Length; i++)
            {
                string p1 = "@valParam" + ((char)(i + 65)).ToString();
                string p2 = param.ValoreParametri[i].ToString();//use variable
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p1, p2);
            }
            cmd.CommandText += ") select scope_identity()";         
            indice = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
        return indice;
    }
```

Comment: You can not have table name as a parameter in the query. Parameters are only for the passing values to queries, not to pass database items in the queries such as table names and column names.

Comment: So the table name must be written on the query? Not as parameters?

Comment: Yes... Also the column names..

Comment: But, i dont undurstand in this case i have modify the column name  and assign the real name and the real value. It's the same of using a query with colName1, colName2 and val1, val2. Just done dinamically,

Comment: ExecuteScalar() one returns the first column from the Select statement.  You want ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: @jdweng i need the index of the last added

Comment: What do you mean by the index?  The SQL Server is multi-threaded and data is not read/and stored in parallel threads.  So index does not mean anything.  The return value from  ExecuteScalar is only valid when you do a SELECT and you are doing an INSERT.

Comment: @jdweng i am adding a record to a table and i need to know his 'id'

Comment: The do another SELECT query to get the id.

Comment: Parameters/Variables cannot be used to replace the name of an object. `SELECT * FROM @TableName` would try to return data from the table variable `@TableName` not the table which has the name of the value *stored* in the scalar variable `@TableName`. If you do need dynamic statements like this, it *normally* implies a design flaw. When you do though, you have to ***safely*** inject the value into the statement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373461/execute-insert-command-and-return-inserted-id-in-sql

Comment: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Return-Identity-Auto-Increment-Column-value-after-record-insert-in-SQL-Server-Database-using-ADONet-with-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i followed your comments and now it works without the previous problem. Thank you . How can i set this question to "Solved" thanks to your comment?