# How to insert new records to two tables at the same time with foreign key relationship

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert values to two tables at the same time. I have a `dbo.Student` and `dbo.Guardian`. The Guardian table has a foreign key studentID. I am trying to insert values to it but it always shows NULL. I am trying to insert both student information and guardian information at the same time in one click of a button. Please help

```
//Save student information
cn.Open();
cm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Student (studentNo, Lname, Fname, MI, gender, yearLevel, section, studImage, isActive)  VALUES (@studentNo, @Lname, @Fname, @MI, @gender, @yearLevel, @section, @studImage, 'true')", cn);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentNo", txtStudentNo.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lname", txtLname.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fname", txtFname.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MI", txtMI.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yearLevel", txtYear.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@section", txtSection.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studImage", img);
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close();


//Save guardian information
cn.Open();
cm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Guardian (studentID, name, address, contactNo) VALUES (@studentID, @name, @address, @contactNo)", cn);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtGuardianName.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtAddress.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactno", txtContactNo.Text);
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close();
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  I also don't recommend `AddWithValue`.  It is better to be explicit about the types.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have edited my tags, thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Use **Entity Framework** or any **ORM** for Database.

**This Option Not Recommended**

To Solve This Problem

**Step 1**
Modified Your **SQL Query**

Check [Execute Insert command and return inserted Id in Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373461/execute-insert-command-and-return-inserted-id-in-sql)

Add below line in **Student Query**

```
output INSERTED.<Student_Table_Primary_Key_Column_Name>
```

**Step 2** Replace **cm.ExecuteNonQuery()** with

```
//Return Inserted Student Table ID
int stdid =(int)cm.ExecuteScalar();
```

**Step 3** Add **stdid** in **Guardian** Table

```
// set Student ID in Guardian Table
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", stdid);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I don't believe `int stdid =(int)cm.ExecuteScalar();` will return the id unless you modify the sql call.

Comment: Good day, it says invalid column name ID

Comment: I don't know where i did wrong

Comment: output INSERTED.<Student_Table_Primary_Key_Column_Name>