# Hibernate insert doesn't work with custom native query

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, hibernate, nativequery

In a spring boot project and database SQL Server, I'm doing some inserts where I need to return the id of the record
I have a Entity with few fields:

```
public class PackGroupEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long group_id;
    private String group;
    private String remark;
    private String description;
    ....
}
```

I simplified the insert just to ask the question.

I have an insert statement and I need to retrieve the id from the inserted record.

```
String query = String.format(
                "insert into pack_group(group, remark, description ) " +
                "values ( %s, %s, %s)", "a","b","c"  );
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query );
BigInteger biid = (BigInteger) q.getSingleResult();
long id = biid.longValue();
```

And I get this error
`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.`

Based on this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49976101/13769578) that I can use `returning id` so I tried but:

```
String query = String.format(
                "insert into pack_group(group, remark, description ) " +
                "values ( %s, %s, %s ) returning group_id;", "a","b","c"  );
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query );
BigInteger biid = (BigInteger) q.getSingleResult();
long id = biid.longValue();
```

but it throws an error

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'returning'.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Do not EVER put in user strings like this. It's a major security vulnerability. Learn how to avoid it from [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/java).

Answer (score 1):

This things is SQL Server **does not support** returning syntax.

If you want get id for inserted row - you should use keyword **output**

This is official docs for using output with INSERT statement:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-using-output-into-with-a-simple-insert-statement

You can also see this answer with examples for different SQL Server version for C# (but query does not different for Java):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18373524/16644196

Answer (score 0):

SQLServer doesn't support the `returning` clause. Instead, use the `output` clause.

```
String query = String.format("INSERT INTO pack_group(group, remark, description) " 
                + "OUTPUT INSERTED.group_id " 
                + "VALUES( %s, %s, %s )", "a","b","c");
```