# Get highest ID number in ID kolumn and increment

Tags: sql, linq, gridview, ado.net, dataset

How would you get the highest ID number from the ID column in a DataSet? I'm using ADO.NET (C#). If I do this:

```
dataSet.Tables["Students"].Columns["ID"].AutoIncrement = true;
```

The application will throw and exception when I reach an ID that is already present. And to start from a "hight number" is just an ugly hack. So How could this be done properly and safely?

I'm adding new rows in a GridView and saving that data to the cache, then from cache back to DataSet and then using the DataAdapter method "Update" to send new data back to SQL Server.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What means "will throw and exception when I reach an ID that is already present"? If the column is an `IDENTITY` column you don't need to insert the value manually. It will be assigned by the database when you insert a record. So you won't know the real number until it was inserted. Then you can use [`SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) to get the value. You can [combine the insert with this select to get this value in one statement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9319609/284240).

Comment: Sorry. The SQL Server has an ID Primary Key column with AutoIncrement. But the DataSet doesn't. So when I add a new record to the DataSet I need to provide an ID. If I just AutoIncrement the ID it will eventually crack the application when two ID values are present. Say I have records in DataSet with ID values of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc. When I add a new record to that DataSet I need to give the new record and ID of value 6, that is higher than the highest ID value present in the DataSet.

Comment: You don't need to assign an ID if it's an `IDENTITY`-column. You just need to insert the other values: `INSERT INTO Students(col2,col3,..) VALUES (@col2,@col3,...); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();`. That insert.statement can be executed with `ExecuteScalar` and you get the new ID-value of the inserted record. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ks9f57t0(v=vs.100).aspx It should also update a `DataTable` with the new ID-value, but here i'm not sure.

Comment: This is offline mode, disconnected data access. You are talking about updating the underlying SQL database. The exception comes from the DataSet not the SQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach, since the value will be inserted from the database because it's an `IDENTITY` column it doesn't really matter what value you assign. But i would use a negative value to indicate that this row is currently not added to the database.

So increment the negative row-count value of the [added-rows `DataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxfaha8(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DataTable tblStudents = dataSet.Tables["Students"];
DataRow addedRow = tblStudents.Rows.Add();
DataTable tblAddedRows = tblStudents.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
addedRow.SetField("ID", -1 * tblAddedRows.Rows.Count);

// other columns...
```

Collisions are impossible since this ID value is just temporary and will be replaced with the real value after the record was inserted.