# sql-c#-insert data to database and output autoincreament id

Tags: sql-server

I want to get Id from sql, this is my sql:

```
INSERT INTO Respondent (Gender) VALUES ('Male') OUTPUT inserted.Id.
```

> error: Incorrect syntax near 'OUTPUT'.

Comment: I would use `scope_identity`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9319609/284240

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `MySQL` and so the error. Use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` instead like

```
INSERT INTO Respondent (Gender) VALUES ('Male');
select LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

If it's `SQL Server` then your syntax is wrong. See [OUTPUT Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). change your query to

```
INSERT INTO Respondent (Gender) 
OUTPUT inserted.Id
VALUES ('Male')
```

Comment: I change to INSERT INTO Respondent (Gender) 
OUTPUT inserted.Id
VALUES ('Male') but error is become to String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: #@KeLiu, that's a altogether separate error and it's because your `Gender` column length which is less than 4 characters. Make the changes accordingly.

Comment: @KeLiu, Welcome. Consider accepting the answer by clicking the check button.