# C# ExecuteSqlCommand Is Not Returning Output From Stored Proceedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My C# `ExecuteSqlCommand` is not returning output from stored procedure.

I actually need last inserted row's `Id`

Here is my Stored Proceedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PatientInsert]
@FirstName nvarchar(Max),
@MiddleName nvarchar(Max),
@LastName nvarchar(Max),
@Gender nvarchar(Max),
@CNICNumber nvarchar(Max),
@DateOfBirth datetime,
@Country nvarchar(max),
@StateOrProvince nvarchar(max),
@City nvarchar(max),
@Address nvarchar(max),
@CellNumber nvarchar(max),
@TelephoneNumber nvarchar(max),
@Email nvarchar(max),
@NOKFirstName nvarchar(max),
@NOKLastName nvarchar(max),
@NOKRelation nvarchar(max),
@NOKCNICNumber nvarchar(max),
@NOKCellNumber nvarchar(max),
@Title int,
@PicturePath nvarchar(max),
@LastCreatedId INT  OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN 
     SET NOCOUNT ON 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Patients]
           ([FirstName]
           ,[MiddleName]
           ,[LastName]
           ,[Gender]
           ,[CNICNumber]
           ,[DateOfBirth]
           ,[Country]
           ,[StateOrProvince]
           ,[City]
           ,[Address]
           ,[CellNumber]
           ,[TelephoneNumber]
           ,[Email]
           ,[NOKFirstName]
           ,[NOKLastName]
           ,[NOKRelation]
           ,[NOKCNICNumber]
           ,[NOKCellNumber]
           ,[Title]
           ,[PicturePath])

     VALUES
          (
            @FirstName ,
            @MiddleName ,
            @LastName ,
            @Gender ,
            @CNICNumber ,
            @DateOfBirth,
            @Country ,
            @StateOrProvince ,
            @City ,
            @Address ,
            @CellNumber ,
            @TelephoneNumber ,
            @Email ,
            @NOKFirstName ,
            @NOKLastName ,
            @NOKRelation ,
            @NOKCNICNumber ,
            @NOKCellNumber ,
            @Title,
            @PicturePath
        )

        SELECT @LastCreatedId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

END
```

I have tested this stored proceedure and it is working perfectly in SQL Server Management Studio

Here Is [Stored Procedure Execution Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6h3w.png) as I am using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and returning it as `OUTPUT` throught `@LastCreatedId`

You can see in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6h3w.png) data is inserting perfectly in database but in C# I can send data correctly to database but can not retentive `OUTPUT` data of `@LastCreatedId`

And here is my C# code to use this stored procedure

```
public int PatientInsert(Patient PatientInstance)
        {
            using (var context = new HMContext())
            {
                try
                {

                    //Int32 LastCreatedId = new Int32();

                    var returnCode = new SqlParameter("@LastCreatedId", SqlDbType.Int);
                    returnCode.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    insertRow =
                    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("PatientInsert @FirstName ,@MiddleName,"
                    +"@LastName,@Gender,@CNICNumber,@DateOfBirth,@Country,@StateOrProvince,@City,"
                    + "@Address,@CellNumber,@TelephoneNumber,@Email,@NOKFirstName,@NOKLastName,@NOKRelation,"
                    + "@NOKCNICNumber,@NOKCellNumber,@Title,@PicturePath,@LastCreatedId",
                    new SqlParameter("@FirstName", PatientInstance.FirstName),
                    new SqlParameter("@MiddleName", PatientInstance.MiddleName),
                    new SqlParameter("@LastName", PatientInstance.LastName),
                    new SqlParameter("@Gender", PatientInstance.Gender),
                    new SqlParameter("@CNICNumber", PatientInstance.CNICNumber),
                    new SqlParameter("@DateOfBirth", PatientInstance.DateOfBirth.Value.ToShortDateString()),
                    new SqlParameter("@Country", PatientInstance.Country),
                    new SqlParameter("@StateOrProvince", PatientInstance.StateOrProvince),
                    new SqlParameter("@City", PatientInstance.City),
                    new SqlParameter("@Address", PatientInstance.Address),
                    new SqlParameter("@CellNumber", PatientInstance.CellNumber),
                    new SqlParameter("@TelephoneNumber", PatientInstance.TelephoneNumber),
                    new SqlParameter("@Email", PatientInstance.Email),
                    new SqlParameter("@NOKFirstName", PatientInstance.NOKFirstName),
                    new SqlParameter("@NOKLastName", PatientInstance.NOKLastName),
                    new SqlParameter("@NOKRelation", PatientInstance.NOKRelation),
                    new SqlParameter("@NOKCNICNumber", PatientInstance.NOKCNICNumber),
                    new SqlParameter("@NOKCellNumber", PatientInstance.NOKCellNumber),
                    new SqlParameter("@Title", PatientInstance.Title.ToString()),
                    new SqlParameter("@PicturePath", (PatientInstance.PicturePath==null?"":PatientInstance.PicturePath)),
                    returnCode
                    );
                    return (int)returnCode.Value;
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    var me = exp.Message;
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
```

I get `{}` value from `returnCode.Value`
And if I try to cast it to integer it gives me exception `Specified cast is not valid.`

What should I do to possibly retrieve value of `@LastCreatedId` as OUTPUT value from the Stored Procedure

Comment: You probably want `Database.ExecuteReader`, not `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
SELECT @LastCreatedId = CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)
```

in stored procedure.. Also do check it contains the int value using the below cast operation

```
if (returnCode.Value != DBNull.Value) 
return Convert.ToInt32(returnCode.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are basically trying to get ID via SCOPE_IDENTITY() why not try using: [ExecuteScalar()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspxhttp://).

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

I took the answer from the post below:
  [Return value from SQL Server Insert command using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319532/return-value-from-sql-server-insert-command-using-c-sharp)

Cheers!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, Try adding the word OUTPUT after the parameter is mentioned in the ExecuteSQLCommand call like this

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("...,@LastCreatedId OUTPUT",...
```

**Your full code would be like:**

```
public int PatientInsert(Patient PatientInstance)
    {
        using (var context = new HMContext())
        {
            try
            {

                //Int32 LastCreatedId = new Int32();

                var returnCode = new SqlParameter("@LastCreatedId", SqlDbType.Int);
                returnCode.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                insertRow =
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("PatientInsert @FirstName ,@MiddleName,"
                +"@LastName,@Gender,@CNICNumber,@DateOfBirth,@Country,@StateOrProvince,@City,"
                + "@Address,@CellNumber,@TelephoneNumber,@Email,@NOKFirstName,@NOKLastName,@NOKRelation,"
                + "@NOKCNICNumber,@NOKCellNumber,@Title,@PicturePath,@LastCreatedId OUTPUT",
                new SqlParameter("@FirstName", PatientInstance.FirstName),
                new SqlParameter("@MiddleName", PatientInstance.MiddleName),
                new SqlParameter("@LastName", PatientInstance.LastName),
                new SqlParameter("@Gender", PatientInstance.Gender),
                new SqlParameter("@CNICNumber", PatientInstance.CNICNumber),
                new SqlParameter("@DateOfBirth", PatientInstance.DateOfBirth.Value.ToShortDateString()),
                new SqlParameter("@Country", PatientInstance.Country),
                new SqlParameter("@StateOrProvince", PatientInstance.StateOrProvince),
                new SqlParameter("@City", PatientInstance.City),
                new SqlParameter("@Address", PatientInstance.Address),
                new SqlParameter("@CellNumber", PatientInstance.CellNumber),
                new SqlParameter("@TelephoneNumber", PatientInstance.TelephoneNumber),
                new SqlParameter("@Email", PatientInstance.Email),
                new SqlParameter("@NOKFirstName", PatientInstance.NOKFirstName),
                new SqlParameter("@NOKLastName", PatientInstance.NOKLastName),
                new SqlParameter("@NOKRelation", PatientInstance.NOKRelation),
                new SqlParameter("@NOKCNICNumber", PatientInstance.NOKCNICNumber),
                new SqlParameter("@NOKCellNumber", PatientInstance.NOKCellNumber),
                new SqlParameter("@Title", PatientInstance.Title.ToString()),
                new SqlParameter("@PicturePath", (PatientInstance.PicturePath==null?"":PatientInstance.PicturePath)),
                returnCode
                );
                return (int)returnCode.Value;
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                var me = exp.Message;
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
```