# How to increment in id in foreign key in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two database tables `dtadd` with columns `address`, `city`, and `id` which is a foreign key, and the other table is `dtperson` with columns `name`, `age` and `id` which is the primary key. All I want to know is how I can increment id in the foreign key.

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "server=.;database = mydata2;integrated security = true";
    con.Open();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1 ; i++)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into dtperson1 (name,age)values('" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "')";

        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();

        cmd.CommandText = "insert into dtadd (address,city)values('" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "')";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    }

    MessageBox.Show("datainserted");
}
```

Comment: what you want to do with increment it's value?

Comment: so i can fetch the person name with id

Comment: you can execute 'select @id = Scope_Identity()' query it will return primary key of recently added row.

Comment: where i can put this query can you plz tel me

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 3):

First you need to set your primary key as auto increment in database
you want to get value of recently added row, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319532/return-value-from-sql-server-insert-command-using-c-sharp)

is the question you are looking for. but in your case if you want to get value of person after adding it's row then you can use

```
 using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
        int newID;
        var cmd = "insert into dtperson1 (name,age)values(@val1,@val2);SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
        using (var insertCommand = new SqlCommand(cmd, con)) {
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
   insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            con.Open();
            newID = (int)insertCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the primary key column with autoincrement in the `dtperson` table.

After inserting the row into `dtperson`, you need to fetch last inserted record id

```
select @id = Scope_Identity()
```

Use this `id` as your foreign key id for the `dtadd` table