# ASP.NET C# loop to add records to multiple SQL tables stops unexpectedly without error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have some code that

1. Looks at the max ID in Table A
2. Fetches the records from Table B with ID > Max ID from the Table A
3. Loops through each record that it needs to add (are these the records from Table A????)
4. Finds all records in Table C that is related to the ID from Table B and inserts those records into Table D.

For some reason the loop stops unexpectedly after fetching and inserting some records with no error.  It stops at random stages. Sometimes it adds 20 records sometimes 100 and sometimes 1000+. Is it to do with my logic or is it a server setting maybe? The web application .Net Framework 4.5 and is hosted on a Windows 2019 Server.

Here is the logic I follow. I specifically don't add the code as it is quite elaborate and I thought I'd share the logic I follow rather to get some suggestions on why this might be happening.

```
GetNewRecords()
  MaxIdA = Select max id in Table A
  Select all records in Table B with id > MaxIdA
  if reader has rows
    While reader.Read
    NextID = reader[0]
    AddNewRecordToTableB()
    Select all records in Table C where IdLink = NextID
    if reader2 has rows
      While reader2.Read
        NewDetail = reader2[..]
        AddNewRecordToTableD()
    Connection2 Dispose


AddNewRecordToTableB()
  Insert into TableB ….


AddNewRecordToTableD()
  Insert into Tabled ….
```

Comment: Do you do any exception handling? If not, add exception handling. If so, for debugging, try re-throwing the exception (ex: `throw ex;`)

Comment: Sounds like it can all be done in the db

Comment: You could do this all in a single SQL batch, no need to loop it in code

Comment: I'd look to see if it's running out of memory or timing out or something like that.

Comment: @CaiusJard I'm not sure how to do it in SQL. When the record is added into table B, there is a identity field that creates a new id for the record entered. I need to add this new id to the records being added in Table D. Table B is the header file while Table D has the detail lines for the order in Table B.

Comment: @NealBurns how would I see if it is running out of memory?

Comment: You might be having issues because this is a bad pattern (but frequently seen) for getting the next id. It's quite possibly all records are being added but they are being "stomped on" by susbequent updates because your logic for getting id's is liable to failure. Using `MAX` to get the next ID is a very bad idea.

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid. Could you possibly suggest a better way of doing it?

Comment: Based on your explanation and psuedo code, I can't actually grasp what you're doing right now. I just recognise `MAX` as a bad way to get new unique id's. Here is a link to sample code that lets you use database identity to guarantee a unique new key. Meanwhile let me try and edit your question to help me understand what you are doing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319532/return-value-from-sql-server-insert-command-using-c-sharp

Comment: I have edited the question to try and clarify what's going on. Can you check my edits and clarify as required? (We currently have five different tables). You really need to get more info in this symptom: _the loop stops unexpectedly_. I'm going to guess that your C# loop does not stop at all - it completes it but there's something wrong with the "elaborate" logic inside. Please find some way to confirm that, i.e. console out log lines. As per other comments, this sounds like something that could be wrapped up in a single stored procedure. That would be faster and less buggy.

Answer (score 1):

> I have some code that looks at the max ID in a table and then fetches the records from another table that has ID > Max ID from the first table. The code then loops through each record that it needs to add and finds all records in Table C that is related to the ID from Table B and adds those records all to Table D.

It sounds like this:

```
INSERT INTO d(column,list,here)
SELECT column,list,here --columns from b and c here
FROM
  b 
  JOIN c ON b.id = c.b_id
WHERE 
  b.id > (SELECT MAX(id) FROM a)
```

column list lengths must be same in insert and select

I'm not sure if you need the join; if no data is needed from B (if C contains all the required data) you can skip B:

```
INSERT INTO d(column,list,here)
SELECT column,list,here --columns from c here
FROM
  c
WHERE 
  c.b_id > (SELECT MAX(id) FROM a)
```